# Why am I receiving a undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery which animates a DIV from top and slides it down:

```
$(document).read(function () {
            $("#mSearch").toggle(
                function () {
                    $("#mSearchB").animate({
                        top: '35'
                    }, 500);
                },
                function () {
                    $("#mSearchB").animate({
                        top: "-35"
                    }, 500);
                }
            );
        });
```

Everytime I click on the `mSearch` link, I keep getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not  a function (anonymous function)`

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Click toggle is deprecated and removed.

Comment: What can I use instead?

Comment: A flag is usually the best solution.

Comment: Please delete this question since it was a typographical error in my part. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Well, you need to check for the good toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/.

Comment: Just wonder who has upvoted this question? Hover on the upvote link to "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". Dude hasn't even tried to use debugger before posting the question.

Comment: Actually I did use the Developer Tools for IE and all it said was the error I posted. If I knew the issue beforehand, I would not have posted it. THANKS :)

Comment: And what did you expect it to show? Something like "jquery prototype has no such thing as 'read' we think you meant 'ready'" :)

Comment: OR somewhere toward the link of the beginning of the comment, "jquery prototype has no such thing as 'read', please reach out to Yury Tarabanko for assistance"

Comment: I removed `toggle` and used `click` along with `jquery data` to achieve my goal. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a typo.  Use `ready`, not `read`.

Comment: Ooooops... I finally saw it. Thanks. I was about to delete the question but you answered it :/